# Bugzilla: can I configure one "urlbase" that works internally and externally?

Tags: bugzilla, fqdn

PROBLEM:

I have Bugzillla 3.6 running on Linux, with a Windows 2008 server for our internal DNS.

I need to set Bugzilla's urlbase" so the *SAME* configuration will work for *INTERNAL* clients (EX: http://bugs.local/bugzilla) as well as *EXTERNAL* clients (EX: http://bugs.mycompany.com/bugzilla).

- External works OK: I configure urlbase to "bugs.mycompany.com/bugzilla", and I'm able to log in to Bugzilla from outside our LAN with no problem.
- Internal doesn't work at all unless I hack :
- WORKAROUND: notepad c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts =>

  ```
  192.168.1.200 http://bugs.mycompany.com
  ```

Q: It seems that urlbase requires a fully qualified domain name (e.g. bugs.mycompany.com).

I absolutely cannot use one FQDN for both external clients (bugs.mycompany.com) and internal clients (bugs.mycompany.local).

Is there ANY "one size fits all" option for Bugzilla's "url_base"??????????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option such as this. If it were possible to configure more than one URLbase, Bugzilla could only know which one to send to a particular client by knowing the details of your internal network - what is an internal IP, and what is an external IP.

The correct fix is to set up your internal company DNS servers to return the value "192.168.1.200" when asked about "bugs.mycompany.com". Then the Right Thing will happen, and you don't have to edit /etc/hosts on every machine.

Gerv

Comment: Hi - thank you for the answer.  Unfortunately, that's absolutely *not* the right thing in Microsoft-land: they expect you to distinguish between "mycompany.local" (internal) and "mycompany.com" (external), then the Microsoft client stack should be configured to look for "bugs" as "bugs.mycompany.local" first.  All of which assumes the client is in an Active Directory environment and all the clients use Microsoft Dynamic DNS.  Sigh...  I do appreciate the response.